# describe command and foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Does "describe table" command shows which field is foreign key? Just like it does in the case of primary key by showing "PRI" in key column.

If not, how can I come to know which field in table is declared as foreign key?

Comment: What RMDB are you using? `sql server`, `mysql` , etc.?

Comment: Look atbthe create statement.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command will give you a detailed description of all columns, constraints, and indexes.

If you're using the `mysql` command-line tool, this output is very verbose so you should run it with the `\G` command to switch to the alternate output format:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE example\G
```

Comment: If id1 is primary key in table t1. And I want to create new table t2 and use id1 in t1 as foreign key in t2. What should be my query? Is this one right?                 create table t2(id2 int primary key, id1 int references t1(id1));

Comment: That sounds like another question. Just post as one and you'll get a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL Server you should be able to use sp_help 'TableName' to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt view :

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
       REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname' AND
      REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
```